# c++ instantiating a protected member from parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance

The code below shows 2 classes person and trouble_maker. In this example i'm a bit confused why the trouble_maker class does not have access to set the variable name that it inherited from person directly in the instantiating list. Why does the trouble_maker object have to be created before i'm able to set the variable name?

```
#include <string>
class person {
    int age;
public:

    person(int age);
protected:
    std::string name;

};

person::person(int age) : age(age) {

}
class trouble_maker : person {
public:
    trouble_maker(std::string name, int age);
};

trouble_maker::trouble_maker(std::string name, int age) : person(age), name(name) //name is not a static memeber
{
    this->name = name; // works fine
}

int main() {
    person a_person();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, because `trouble_maker` privately inherits `person`, a `trouble_maker` is-not-a `person`.  (Can't be used for Liskov's substitution.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079739/c-error-initializing-base-class-data-member-in-the-derived-class-member-initia  (and dozens of others, i'm certain).

Comment: It has access. You're just not doing it the right way. The `:` behind the constructor is for initialization of the class members only. You can call the base constructor however, but you have no constructor for name in the base. Assignment is possible in the constructor, but you need to put it between the braces.

Comment: @whozcraig why didn't you flag duplicate, but only put the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The member intializer list following the `:` after the constructor head does not do any assignment of variables. Instead it specifies for each non-static direct data member and base class of the class an initializer with which these members or base classes are going to be initialized.

`name` is not a direct member of `trouble_maker`. It is not `trouble_maker`'s job to initialize it. That is `person`'s job.

Members and base classes are initialized top-down. First the bases class are initialized, then the direct members of the class. While the `person` subobject is created and initialized, the derived `trouble_maker` object doesn't even exist yet. Therefore it must be `person` that initializes `name`.

If you want to initialize `name` differently in `trouble_maker` than in `person`, you need to write a constructor for `person` that does the initialization for `trouble_maker`. `trouble_maker` can then call this constructor in the member initializer list, the same way you already do here: `: person(age),`.

The later `this->name = name;` is not initialization, but assignment. Since you made `name` `protected` rather than `private`, `trouble_maker` is allowed to assign to `name`, but it is still not able to initialize `name` without going through a constructor of `person`.